# Mini cart content not rendering properly in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, mini-cart

I am using Magento 2.3

I have custom header and I have added minicart in the header but the issue is that content is not rendering in minicart properly.

Please refer below screenshot:
[image]

As you can see in above image I have 2 quantity of same products in my cart but product is not displaying in minicart popup

I have added below code in my header file:

```
<div class="cart">
  <?php  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
</div>
```

> minicart.phtml

```
<?php /**  * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.  * See COPYING.txt for license details.  */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */ ?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getShoppingCartUrl() ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('My Cart') ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()): ?>
        <div class="block block-minicart"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
        window.checkout = <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif') ?>"
        }
    }
    </script> </div>
```

[image]

also summary count is not displaying as well.

So how can I add minicart in header without any issues?

Comment: Check console errors then you will get idea what is the exact issue.

Comment: @SukumarGorai I have checked in console but I think there is no error regarding minicart please check my edited question

Comment: Can you solve those errors first? I think these error might stop minicart to render.